# Magento: Implementing Channel Intelligence tag

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying add the tracking tag for Channel Intelligence to a Magento store, and they have provided the code that tells which variables to populate, but I don't know how to add the variable specific to Magento, but it should be the same for all Magento sites. I've scoured the net and cannot find any references to it, but it shouldn't be that difficult.

Any help?

Here are the fields:

```
var CI_ItemIDs = new Array ('SKU123','SKU456');(SKU values)
var CI_ItemPrices = new Array('15.00','50.00');(current sale price of the products)
var CI_ItemAvailability = new Array('1','0'); (1=in stock, 0=out of stock,-­‐1=no update,-­‐2=limited availability,-­‐3=backorder,-­‐4=preorder)
var CI_OrderID = 'ORD123';
var CI_ItemIDs = new Array('SKU123','SKU456');
var CI_ItemQtys = new Array('1','3');
var CI_ItemPrices = new Array('15.00','50.00');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That kind of depends on where you are needing the values, but assuming you want to put this in the product detail page, you would edit /app/design/frontend/yourtheme/catalog/product/view.phtml. At the top of that page, there should be a line like this:

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
```

Then use getData(), so to assign an SKU to channel Intelligence:

```
var CI_ItemIDs = new Array ('<?php echo $_product->getData('sku'); ?>');
```

I don't have the specifics, but it would be the same process for the order ids, etc.